# Using with alias when subproject matches Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using

My companies website has a folder called "Domain" in the SolutionName.Website (the sln) with a bunch of projects. It also contains a project named "Domain" in the Domain folder. This is becoming incredibly annoying as when I want to alias "SolutionName.Website.Domain" to "Domain" the compiler goes nuts as it no longer knows if I'm referring to projects/items in the Domain folder or objects in the Domain project (Files in the domain project have namespaces of SolutionName.Website.Domain which seems to be the naming structure).
For code visibility purposes this is problematic as it means I have to reference every type in domain by its full path, or alias every type.
Is there anyway around this problem without changing either the folder or project name?

Thank You